# How to hide text/div and replace it with asterisks?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I need some help.. the idea behind this is like a simple toggle button that can hide the object and replacing the empty area with ****.

I was thinking it was more like in a Password form input where you can hide password by clicking the Eye icon. However, I needed something that are not required input form, something that is just simple DIV

```js
function toggler(divId) {
    $("#" + divId).toggle();
    .css('content', 'sadas');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
     display:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggler('myContent');">this is a test</a>
<div id="myContent" class='hidden'>
  <div>this is a test #1 </div>
</div>
```

I can hide the DIV but leaving the empty area, how can I replace this empty area with ***** ??

example:
My balance is $200 [hide]
My balance is **** [show]

https://jsfiddle.net/qobgfLh6/

Comment: You have an error here 
$("#" + divId).toggle(); <-- you cant close the line if u want to add the .css function to it
    .css('content', 'sadas');

Comment: Also, please update your post title. Replace Hi with How. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a fiddle.
There are some points that can be better managed.
But I think you are looking for something like that.

The idea is to add another div with the **** placeholder and use toggleClass() function of jQuery.

```
$("#" + divId).toggleClass('hidden');
$("#myPlaceholder").toggleClass('hidden');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qze8fydv/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
  function handle(input, toggler) {
    var inputValue = ""
    var shouldShowAsterisks = false
  
    input.change(function () {
      inputValue = $(this).val()
    })
  
    toggler.click(function () {
      shouldShowAsterisks = !shouldShowAsterisks
      shouldShowAsterisks
      ? input.val("*".repeat(inputValue.length))
      : input.val(inputValue)
      input.prop("disabled", shouldShowAsterisks)
    })
  }

  handle($(".enter"), $(".toggler"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="enter" />
    <button class="toggler">Hide</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggleElementMask(element){
  //Regex to find *
  let reg = /^\*+$/g;
  //If all * we are masked
  let isMasked = element.innerText.match(reg);
  if(!isMasked) {
    //Store the original text
    element.dataset.original = element.innerText;
    //Replace the contente with the same amount of *
    element.innerText = "*".repeat(element.innerText.length);
  }else{
    //Restore the text
    element.innerText = element.dataset.original;
  }
}

//Mask on page load
$(".masked").each(function(){
  toggleElementMask(this);
});

//Click event handler
$(".toggleMask").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  toggleElementMask($($(this).attr("href"))[0]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#myContent" class="toggleMask"> this is a test</a>
<div id="myContent" class='masked'>
  <div>this is a test #1 </div>
</div>

<a href="#myContent2" class="toggleMask"> this is a test</a>
<div id="myContent2" class='masked'>
  <div>Another one</div>
</div>


<a href="#myContent3" class="toggleMask"> this is a test</a>
<div id="myContent3" class='masked'>
  <div>one with <span>a</span> span</div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, finally! thank you so much providing more than one because I forgot to mention that I needed 3 div to be hide and display