# Show and Hide the text with stars on clicking the button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a paragraph tag with number init. I want to replace the numbers with stars/round circles on clicking the button beside it. Also, I am attaching a screenshot to which I want to apply the concept(on clicking the eye icon the Patient Id should be replaced with round circles and vice versa). Attaching the code which I have tried. Your solutions are very important for me in learning the things. TIA

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFeuu.jpg)

```js
 $('.hide-id').on('click', function () {
   $('.patient-id-content').attr('type', 'password');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="container">
    <p>
      <span class="patient-id-content" type="text">34324345</span>
      <button class="hide-id">
        Hide
      </button>
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your span should be an input `<input class="patient-id-content" type="text" value="34324345">` to start with :)

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66054137/how-to-hide-text-div-and-replace-it-with-asterisks

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, Thanks for your answer. But, I am not looking for input one. You can check the image link in question, that is the pattern I am trying for.

Comment: the attribute type is avalaible for `<button>, <input>, <command>, <embed>, <object>, <script>, <source>, <style>, <menu>, <link>` elements , not span and has for each different values and purpose. So if you do want to use a span, forget the attribute type ;)

Comment: Thanks all for responding with your way of solutions. With the help of all solutions, I have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need.

```
 $(".hide-id").on("click", function () {
      var span = $(".patient-id-content");
      var spanText = span.text();
      if (!spanText.indexOf("*")) {
        $(".patient-id-content").text(span.attr("data-oldText"));
        return;
      }

      var starText = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < spanText.length; i++) starText += "*";
      $(".patient-id-content")
        .attr("data-oldText", spanText)
        .text(starText);
    });
```

working example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ynojkf0q/

Comment: Thanks, your solution helped me in fixing my issue.

Answer (score 1):

So your jQuery code from the OP was not correct. You have what you want as the password in a `span` and are applying a type attribute to that.

If you check the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span#attributes), you will learn that there is no `type` attribute for a span, as spans only support [Global Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes). The `input` element uses both the `type: text` and `type: password`, see the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password).

But if you want to have the span as your element, you can change your jQuery event handler to the following: `.toggleClass('hidden');` and create a hidden CSS class with the properties `display: none;`

```js
$('.hide-id').on('click', function () {
   $('.patient-id-content').toggleClass('hidden');
 });
```

```css
.hidden { display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <p>
      <input class="patient-id-content" type="text" value="34324345">      
      <button class="hide-id">
        Hide
      </button>
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing me the solution

Comment: I don't have enough points to upvote. However, I have clicked on Upvote and it has been recorded.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution for the functionality you want.  It will need more styling to get it to look exactly the the example you provided above.

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
    <p>
      <input class="patient-id-content" type="password" value="34324345">
      <button id="pass-toggle" class="hide-id" onclick="toggleShowPassword()">
        Show
      </button>
    </p>
  </div>
```

JS

```
let passwordVisible = false;
 
 function toggleShowPassword() {
    let inputType = 'password';
  passwordVisible = !passwordVisible;
  
  
  if (passwordVisible) {
    inputType = 'text';
    $('#pass-toggle').addClass( "show-id" ).text( 'Hide' );
  } else {
     $('#pass-toggle').removeClass( "show-id" ).text( 'Show' );
  }
  
  $('.patient-id-content').attr('type', inputType);
```

CSS

```
.patient-id-content {
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing me the solution

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

to have hidden by default:

```html
<span class="patient-id-content" type="text" data-patient-id="34324345" data-visible="false">********</span>
```

to show by default:

```html
<span class="patient-id-content" type="text" data-patient-id="34324345" data-visible="true">34324345</span>
```

```js
$('.hide-id').on('click', function () {
  const patientId = $(this).prev('span'); // dependent on this DOM placement
  const patientIdValue = patientId.attr('data-patient-id');
  const isShowing = patientId.data('visible');
  const valueToShow = isShowing ? '********' : patientIdValue;

  patientId.text(valueToShow);
  patientId.data('visible', !isShowing)
});
```

Included a JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w7shxztp/20/

Comment: Thanks for providing me the solution

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue with the below solution:

```js
$(".icofont-eye").on("click", function() {
  $('#Patient-id-icon-element').toggleClass('icofont-eye-blocked');
  $('#Patient-id-icon-element').toggleClass('icofont-eye');
  var patientIdcontent = $(".patient-id-content");
  var patientIdcontentText = patientIdcontent.text();

  if (patientIdcontentText.indexOf("*")) {
    $(".patient-id-content").text('***************');
  } else {
    $(".patient-id-content").text('3d4532403d453240');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row mt-1">
  <div class="col-4 text-right mychart-label">Patient ID</div>
  <div class="col-8 section-content">
    <span class="patient-id-content">****************</span> <span class="patient-id-icon">
        <a class="icofont icofont-eye cl-icon-1-point-3x mt-1" id="Patient-id-icon-element" type="button">Show</a>
    
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```